# Merge videos in c# asp.net using ffmpeg

Tags: c#, asp.net, merge, ffmpeg

Is it possible to merge the two videos by c# asp.net with the help of ffmpeg. In the ffmpeg documentation they gave us cat command. But it wont works in asp.net. I thought it only for linux.

```
cat intermediate1.mpg intermediate2.mpg > intermediate_all.mpg
```

asp.net execute this command but there is no output. Help me.

```
namespace demo
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strFile = "cars1.flv";
            MergeFiles(strFile);
        }

        public void MergeFiles(string strFile)
        {
            string strParam;
            string Path_FFMPEG = Server.MapPath("~/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe");

            //Converting a video into mp4 format
            string strOrginal = Server.MapPath("~/Videos/");
            strOrginal = strOrginal + strFile;
            string strConvert = Server.MapPath("~/Videos/ConvertedFiles/");
            string strExtn = Path.GetExtension(strOrginal);
            if (strExtn != ".mp4")
            {
                strConvert = strConvert + strFile.Replace(strExtn, ".mp4");
                strParam  = "-i " + strOrginal + " " + strConvert;
                //strParam = "-i " + strOrginal + " -same_quant " + strConvert;
                process(Path_FFMPEG, strParam);
            }

            //Merging two videos               
            String video1 = Server.MapPath("~/Videos/Cars1.mp4");
            String video2 = Server.MapPath("~/Videos/ConvertedFiles/Cars2.mp4");
            String strResult = Server.MapPath("~/Videos/ConvertedFiles/Merge.mp4");
            //strParam = "-loop_input -shortest -y -i " + video1 + " -i " + video2 + " -acodec copy -vcodec mjpeg " + strResult;

            strParam = " -i " + video1 + " -i " + video2 + " -acodec copy -vcodec mjpeg " + strResult;

            process(Path_FFMPEG, strParam);
        }

        public void process(string Path_FFMPEG, string strParam)
        {
            try
            {
                Process ffmpeg = new Process();
                ProcessStartInfo ffmpeg_StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path_FFMPEG, strParam);
                ffmpeg_StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                ffmpeg_StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                ffmpeg_StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                ffmpeg.StartInfo = ffmpeg_StartInfo;
                ffmpeg_StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                ffmpeg.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                ffmpeg.Start();
                ffmpeg.WaitForExit();
                ffmpeg.Close();
                ffmpeg.Dispose();
                ffmpeg = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You allready asked it, if im not mistake?!

Comment: @vcsjones i showed my code dude. It executes with out any errors. But it wont give any output files in the specified directory.

Comment: @Likurg Ya i asking it from yesterday itself dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the answer for my own question.

The following method resolves my problem.

```
public void MergeFiles(string strFile)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/app.bat");
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
            p.Dispose();
        }
```

**app.bat**

The app.bat contains the following code.

```
copy e:\cars1.mpg /b + e:\cars2.mpg /b e:\output.mpg /b
```

NOTE: This is for windows only. That's why "cat" command doesn't works. Instead of "cat" command we use copy command.

Comment: the videos are merged, the size is doubled but it duration doesn't move, not working for me, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Creating app. Bat file double the file size but it play as single. Still problem not resolved. You should try ffmpeg concat command approach in which you need to create a text file that contain files names and this file should be on same folder where mp4 file are. the below code will help you i was facing the same issue. My task was to merge two mp4 files and I merge successfully when I was doing it from Command prompt. But stuck when I was doiing it through asp. Net. My issue resolved by given correct path and remove ffmpeg from command. For E. G( ffmepg - f concat TO - f concat)

Dim _ffmpeg As String = "D:\Develop\Experiment\mergermp4Vb\mergermp4Vb\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
Dim   params = "-f concat -i D:\Develop\Experiment\mergermp4Vb\mergermp4Vb\Videos\mylist2.txt -c copy D:\Develop\Experiment\mergermp4Vb\mergermp4Vb\Videos\0104.mp4"
Dim _FFmpegProcessPropertys As New ProcessStartInfo
_FFmpegProcessPropertys.FileName = _ffmpeg

```
_FFmpegProcessPropertys.Arguments = params
_FFmpegProcessPropertys.UseShellExecute = False
_FFmpegProcessPropertys.RedirectStandardOutput = True
_FFmpegProcessPropertys.RedirectStandardError = True
_FFmpegProcessPropertys.CreateNoWindow = True
Dim FFmpegProcess = Process.Start(_FFmpegProcessPropertys)
```